# PopupWindow Width and Height

Tags: android, height, width, popupwindow

OK, so I am starting to get a hang of building Android apps, well at least as much a programmer can after a few days - I am proud of what I have learned so far.

Anyways, I want to force login on the main activity - this I am doing by fetching a SharedPrefernece and than checking if that piece of information is null and than getting a PopupWindow which holds the "login" fields and options.

This PopupWindow has a Flipper inside, which is fine and I got working fine when the certain options are choosen.

I am having problems displaying this PopupWindow to just be the size of the content (wrap_content) as when I set the PopupWindow.setAtLocation()

Now, here is what I have been trying to do to get the size of the popup - as mentioned a few times on here:

```
popup.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popup,popup.getMeasuredHeight(),popup.getMeasuredWidth(), true);
```

Note that popup is the inflator of the actual layout of the Popup, pw is the actual PopupWindow object.

Now, I want to get the actual size of just the popup window (so that way it isn't streched out over the page, but rather just in the center looking like a normal popup should.

Also, with the ViewFlipper. I want it to update the size of the popup when it switch pages (so the page should be sizing up and down per page) is there a way to make this work as well? I tried pw.update() but that didn't work out very well.

Answer (score 1):

You want to measure the actual layout you will be adding to your `PopupWindow`.  I just solved a similar problem of putting a `ListView` inside a `PopupWindow`.  The trick is to override `onMeasure()` in your `View`.  Remeasure that `ViewFlipper` everytime it changes.

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int x, int y)
{
    super.onMeasure(x, y);

    if(x == View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && y == View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    {
        //measure your child views here

        //tell the view it has been measured
        this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```